# The "isRunning" property is missing in the "() => void" type and is required in the "EffectCb" type.ts(2741)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this code. why does it work with const and not with let. I know the solution to my problem, I would like to know the reason why ts works normally in this case with const

```
type EffectCb = {
  (): void;
  isRunning: boolean;
}
export function effect(cb: VoidFunction) {
  
  let(const) effectCb: EffectCb = () => {
    
    if (effectCb.isRunning) {
      return;
    }
    effectCb.isRunning = true;
    runningEffect = effectCb;
    try {
      cb();
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("ошибка произошла в еффекте!!!");
      throw e;
    } finally {
      runningEffect = null;
      effectCb.isRunning = false;
    }
  };
  effectCb.isRunning = false
  effectCb();
```

}

I'd like to hear the real reason

Comment: See the linked q/a for more info.